# Text bleeding into another DIV element

Tags: css, html

I have an issue with an absolute positioned DIV. Its positioned to the right of an image, and underneath it is another DIV. On fullscreen, it looks fine, but when I resize my browser window, the text goes into the bottom DIV. I just want the browser to make a scrollbar so the text can continue horizontally. Here is my issue on Jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9hpVT/

You have to resize the width of the browser to see the problem

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="d1">
        <img src="abc.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="d2">Here is a long line of text that will overlap the bottom portion I do not want it to do this because it is very bad for my design. Someone please help me out!</div>
    <div id="d3">I don't want to be interrupted!</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#d1 {
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

#d2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Comment: #d1, #d2 { float: left;} fix the issue.

Comment: @VijayakumarSelvaraj No it won't, that would be horrible only #d1 should be floated. Try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the position is absolute.
I would use float instead of positioning for this. See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hpVT/1/).

```
#d1 {
    float: left;
}
#d2 {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9hpVT/5/)

You dont need to do anything with `#d2,#d3` . All you have to do is apply `float:left` to the d1 that contains the image !

Comment: TRUE :) Then we can also add margin-left:100px(since the pic itself is of 80px wide). That would be technically be 20px from each side.